# Upside-down down bow

Tags: notation, cello, bowing

On my Cello Salut D'amour by Elgar score, it has upside-down down bow symbols on it. Does this just mean up bow? I have this on other pieces too:

[image]

[Salut d'amour, Op.12 (Elgar, Edward)](https://imslp.org/wiki/Salut_d%27amour,_Op.12_(Elgar,_Edward))

- Mainz: Schott, 1899, 1901. Plate 26657.
- Violine (transposed, D major)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is the french down bow sign, which is the same thing as normal down bow.

Comment: Yes, they have the same meaning. But this is not "french" but a tradition of certain music publishers and engravers, notably *Durand*.

Comment: I did some searching online, and that's what I found. Considering that Durand is a French publisher, that is not surprising.

Comment: According to OP, the example is from a Russian publisher, which also supports the notion that it is a French convention.