# Why does this edition use an upside-down up-bow to indicate down-bow?

Tags: notation, cello, bowing

I have a piece here that uses *upside-down* **up-bows** to indicate **down-bow**, which I have never seen before. Since I know other editions of the same opus, I know that they have the meaning of a normal **down-bow**. Does anyone know anything about this? Yesterday I confused this example with the post about [Upside-down down-bows](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/43196/42816), but here it obviously is a different matter. Does it have to to with the engraving technique of a certain time or area, since this print is from Russia as stated below?

[image]

[Sebastian Lee; Op. 30](https://imslp.org/wiki/M%C3%A9thode_pratique_pour_le_violoncelle,_Op.30_(Lee,_Sebastian)) - St. Petersburg: M. Bernard, n.d.(ca.1873).

Answer (score 9):

He explains this right at the start of the book (First Edition, from IMSLP).

Tirez = pull, Poussez = push. In other words, ^ is a different notation for a down bow.
[image]

Comment: RTFM FTW!  :-) .  Ain't it amazing what people miss?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft yes exactly! Seems like this comment applies mostly to itself, though a question is not a manual. ;-) +1 for adding this snippet, but it does not really answer the question. I was rather gaining towards some background information about why this upside-down symbol was used in certain editions instead of the common down-bow symbol.

Answer (score 0):

There's rarely a 'why' answer to this sort of question.   You've now enriched your musical knowledge by knowing it happens.  Yes, it could be confused with a marcato symbol. But the notation has been explained in this edition.  Good.

Answer (score -1):

The **^** symbol in music, for a violin, generally indicates a **Marcato** bow, where you push down on the string more or put more force. **It's an accent**, but instead of playing it like **>**, (where you emphasize the **start** of the note) it looks like **^** because you're pretty much emphasizing the **entire note**, not just the start. Think of it as a **50% sfz.**

Comment: While this is correct in general, it doesn't describe the meaning of this symbol in this edition, where it indicates downbow.